# Save image in browser memory with php fileread() function

Tags: php, caching, browser

Can I save image in browser cache with fileread() php function?

Because every time I enter the page it redownload the image.

I try used in php file:

```
header('content-type:image/jpeg');
fileread('my-image.jpg');
```

and in HTML page I used:

```
<img src='my_php_path'>
```

and every time I redownload the page the image redownload.

Can I make it in cache?

Comment: Send the correct headings telling the browser to cache the image, e.g. `header('Pragma: public'); header('Cache-Control: max-age=86400'); header('Expires: '. gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time() + 86400));`

Comment: thank you very much :) 
i put your code in php page and it works